# BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am running a Java (TIBCO EBX) in linux server with 192 GB RAM and we are constantly seeing Java process getting restarted and application will go into hang state, with High Memory alerts. We had set the heap size as 176 GB and we are seeing Heap size is getting full after 10 hours of interval with memory utilization never going down. If we restart the server, memory utilization will go down. We tried to get the Kdump for the server to analyze memory leak and in vmcore-dmesg.txt, we are seeing below entries. Can anyone suggest if this is causing our memory leak and how we can fix this issue ?

```
[  389.832835] SysRq : Trigger a crash
[  390.049124] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
[  390.050076] IP: [<ffffffffbb270326>] sysrq_handle_crash+0x16/0x20
[  390.050076] PGD 80000017c6c6e067 PUD 17fa9c8067 PMD 0
```

Our Kernel version is below :-

```
$uname -r 
3.10.0-1062.52.2.el7.x86_64

$ uname -a
Linux sr001 3.10.0-1062.52.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 8 09:03:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any other advice/suggestion to look.

Comment: It might be related. Maybe some code is assigning NULL to the pointer without freeing it first. So the memory lingers, and then you dereference the null pointer. But without the NULL assignment you'd still have a bug, dereferencing a freed pointer.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it's practically impossible to say.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your suggestions. How can I find a piece of code which is giving this issue ? Any suggestions

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I've never tried to debug kernel code.

Comment: @Barmar ok  but we are sure this is some kernel bug and it might cause the memory leak. I will try to raise a case with RHEL support.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior, so it's clearly a bug. It's probably unrelated to the memory leak, I was just stretching to come up with a possible link.

Comment: Those messages are normal when triggering a crash with the magic SysRq hack.

Comment: The `sysrq_handle_crash()` function in "drivers/tty/sysrq.c" is called to handle the SysRq-triggered crash. In the 3.10 kernel, the code is like this: `char *killer = NULL;` `panic_on_oops = 1;` `wmb();` `*killer = 1;`. It is that last line that triggers the "unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference" message. It's not really a bug because it is deliberate. In kernel 5.0, the function manages the deliberate crash in a nicer way: `/* release the RCU read lock before crashing */` `rcu_read_unlock();` `panic("sysrq triggered crash\n");`.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel dmesg messages are a result of deliberately triggering a crash through the SysRq mechanism (either using the magic SysRq key combination Alt-SysRq followed by `c`, or by writing `c` to the "/proc/sysrq-trigger" file). (Those require the SysRq mechanism to be enabled in the kernel.) They are unrelated to the memory leak.

When the kernel crash is triggered by the SysRq mechanism, the `sysrq_handle_crash()` function in "drivers/tty/sysrq.c" (since kernel 2.6.37). For the 3.10 kernel, it the function definition is as follows:

```c
static void sysrq_handle_crash(int key)
{
    char *killer = NULL;

    panic_on_oops = 1;  /* force panic */
    wmb();
    *killer = 1;
}
```

That `*killer = 1;` line triggers the bug that results in a kernel panic. But it is not really a bug because it was deliberately done that way.

No doubt the `BUG:` message will have alarmed some people. In kernel 5.0, the function was changed to avoid the deliberate null pointer dereference and just call `panic()` directly, as follows:

```c
static void sysrq_handle_crash(int key)
{
    /* release the RCU read lock before crashing */
    rcu_read_unlock();

    panic("sysrq triggered crash\n");
}
```

(The `rcu_read_unlock()` call is only there because `rcu_read_lock()` is called before this function is called.)

---

I suspect the memory leak is probably in the application rather than in the kernel. One way to tell is by killing the application. If the memory leak is in the application, the memory usage should return to normal when its processes are killed. If the memory leak is in the kernel, the memory remains unavailable for further use until the kernel is rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified whether you are using the TIBCO EBX version 5.x or 6.x .But assuming you are using the version 6.x , it can be caused due to a number of reasons :

1. The setup(webserver (commonly Tomcat),database setup) is not done properly.
2. There can be indexing issues (This will not be present if you are using TIBCO EBX 5.x as indexing concept was introduced in the TIBCO EBX 6.x).
3. Any of the processes (bulk data load , complex workflows) are making the system slow and it is not able to read internal jar files.
   4.It also might be caused by what kind of volume you are using. For example if you are using AWS , then whether you are using EBS/EFS/FSx

You can use any of the profilers like VisualVM (helps to take snapshots/thread dumps of the application processes) to check whether any process is consuming too much CPU.

If that doesn't helps you can reach out to TIBCO Support.